# Which is the correct SRS to cut a map?

Tags: dictionary, openlayers

I have used MapTiler to cut a image, steps:

1. Choose "Google Maps Comatible(Spherical Mercator)".
2. Add the image.
3. Choose "WGS84-Latitude and Longitude(geodetic)".
4. Set min zoom 0,and max zoom 4.

Then I got 5 folders named "0","1","2","3" and "4".

I used `OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ` to show this map,but got upper and lower dislocation.
Where is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I use "EPSG:900913" as the SRS whenever dealing with Google maps.